# Application does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a C# forms application.  I import an additional CS file into the program and now it  doesn't compile any more. Every time I try compile i get the following messages:

```
Application does not contain a definition for 'EnableVisualStyles'
Application does not contain a definition for 'SetCompatibleTextrenderingDefault'
Application does not contain a definition for 'Run'
```

When I click on the errors it bring me to Programs.cs.  It just contains the following information:

```
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

One more point, a test console app works fine, however I want this app to be forms application.

Comment: Well, the problem is not here, the problem is within the other files you are importing. Try to add/remove parts of the added code until you understand what parts that causes the error and what parts that are working.

Comment: What's in the "additional CS file?"

Comment: Sounds to me like you're missing some assembly in there. Can you post the "using..." part on the top of your file?

Comment: You added a new class to your project.  Also named "Application".  It hides the System.Windows.Forms.Application class.  Pick another name or tinker with your *using* directives at the top of the source code file or spell out the class name in full.

Comment: if you are running into `name collision` try `Aliasing` the other class  for example `using myApp = Application` or `fully qualified namespace` will resolve the issue..

Comment: Show additional CS file content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You added a new `using` statement for a namespace that has another definition of `Application`, (it might be your own) and that is taking precedence.  You can use the fully qualified name to be sure that you're targeting the right `Application` class:

```
global::System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
global::System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
global::System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new Form1());
```

(You can omit the `global::` as long as you don't also have a class named `System` but the above is just a tad more robust in the fact of ambiguous namespace/class names.

Other alternatives include renaming the custom `Application` class, if it is indeed your own, not adding a `using` for whatever namespace it's in for this file (or any file that uses the `System.Windows.Forms` `Application` class), adding an alias for `System.Windows.Forms.Application` (this is done by something like `using FormApplication = System.Windows.Forms.Application;`), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when using the Entity Model Framework to connect to a database that happened to have a table named "Application".  Once the classes were generated for the database, I immediately had two "Application" classes which caused the error in question.  In my Program.cs file's Main() method, the following code change fixed the issue:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();         
System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new MyForm());
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a necro-bump but it applies to my situation today.  @James G's answer above made me realize that I had imported a web service that contained a definition for "Application" which also caused this error.  As part of your checking things, make sure that any imported services don't incidentally contain "Application."

If anyone is importing it, DynamicsSecurityAdminService is the one that did it to me.